# How to Write A Large Number of Small Data to Single file Efficiently in a Cluster?

Tags: file, io, filesystems

Suppose each of 1000 CPUs writes an integer to a shared file in a cluster. Those 1000 CPUs are on different nodes in the cluster. What is the efficient way to complete those writes fast? GPFS parallel file system is available in the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

From a file system/hard disk perspective, an efficient way to write would be to write large sequential writes. On a cluster, the write size for each node should be sufficient that the write size is bigger than the rotation cost.

In that sense, it makes sense to cache all the integers into a buffer in memory and then write the big buffer to disk.

Now, the question to ask is: what is the ordering requirement? If each integer has to be ordered in time, then a lazy/delayed write may change the order. So, if ordering is important, then timestamping and them sorting at a later time might be used.

Comment: The order of the integers does not matter. Those 1000 integers are written by different, say 1000, programs. So they can not be buffered in memory by a program.